Large U.S corporate hiring who is from sanctioned country but with EU permaneny residency
From U.S sanction and export control point of view, I would like to know if it's possible for a large corporate U.S company who has to fulfill U.S export control law to hire someone for their EU office who has a citizenship of a sanctioned country but he/she has a permanent residency in that particular country where the office is located.
From what I heard it is not possible to hire if the individual is under regular work visa, but a permanent residency would allow the company to hire that individual. is that correct?

Pretty sure that this question has been asked before at Law.SE although I don't know if it was answered. See, e.g., this similar question. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/87805/can-a-company-in-germany-hire-a-remote-worker-from-iran

Another related thread: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/105584/what-happens-when-two-laws-contradict-each-other
